# MVC3 client validation not working

Tags: validation, client, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a required annotation on my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose an option")]
public bool? AnyDebts { get; set; }
```

I have enabled client validation in the web.config:

```
   <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have referenced the jquery scripts in my layout:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What else do I need to do to make client validation work?
Server side validation is still working.

EDIT:

Ah ha!

I have found that client side validation is working.

However, specifically, I have found that model properties are not being validated client side are those annotated with custom attributes.
For example:

```
[BooleanRequiredToBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "You must agree to the statements listed")]
public bool StatementAgree { get; set; }
```

The code for the attribute:

```
public class BooleanRequiredToBeTrueAttribute: RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

Are these not validated client side anymore?

Comment: why are you calling jquery twice?

Answer (score 6):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

are the only required scripts for client validation to work.

And as always here's a full working demo:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose an option")]
    public bool? AnyDebts { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>Debts</div>
    <span>Yes</span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.AnyDebts, true)
    <span>No</span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.AnyDebts, false)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AnyDebts)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Remark: I haven't included `jquery-1.4.4.js` in my view because it is already referenced in the layout.

Comment: Any ideas on this one @Darin Dimitrov? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663563/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-validation-and-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this code.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Enums.BasicOperationType BasicOperationType { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfAttribute(string propertyName, Enums.BasicOperationType BasicOperationType)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
        this.BasicOperationType = BasicOperationType;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Type objectType = validationContext.ObjectType;
        PropertyInfo[] neededProperties = objectType.GetProperties().Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name == PropertyName).ToArray();
        if (Core.Helpers.EnumHelper.TryParse<Enums.BasicOperationType>(Convert.ToInt16(neededProperties[0].GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null))) == BasicOperationType)
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

        return base.IsValid(0, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it only happens when using IE in quirks mode, my settings are Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: Quirks. This results in client side validation not working for me. However, the same page works well in Firefox,Chrome, and IE9, Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 standards when using the developer toolbar. Not that its a solution, but a possible lead