# IE 8 jquery form submit event not firing - MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

Got my self into a problem in IE 8 only. When i reference the following 2 together then the form submit event doesn't fire. When i remove either one then the event fires ok.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Script("jqueryMain/jquery.validate.js")"></script
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Script("jqueryMain/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

js call

```
<script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#TransfersSearchForm").submit(function () {
                    alert(1);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Do i need to download the latest?

Comment: Suggestion: Create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: My jquery.validate.js is changed per the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288753/mvc3-client-side-validation

Comment: I am trying to create this but how do i reference the 2 js files on jsfiddle?

Comment: As specified in my this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288753/mvc3-client-side-validation, if i switch the commented code (selected answer) then the submit event fires just fine but validation doesn't happen. So the commented/uncommented code in these 2 posts fix one and create one issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded the latest jquery.validation.js and IE8 problem got fixed.

Link to download:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/